# Why does atomic_load with a shared_ptr not compile with gcc 4.9?

Tags: c++11, gcc

This doesn't compile using gcc 4.9.3 (from the docker repo):

```
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    auto n = std::atomic_load(&p);
}
```

To test with the gcc docker version (you can just copy-paste the whole block):

```
docker run -it gcc:4.9 bash
# create a test.cpp with previous code:
cat > test.cpp << EOF
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
 auto p = std::make_shared<int>(3);
 auto n = std::atomic_load(&p);
}

EOF
# and compile:
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o bla
```

Fails to compile with 4.9, succeeds with 5.1, although [the C++0x/C++11 compatibility page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) doesn't mention any troubles

Just posting this here because I just lost several hours to figure out the problem, so no one else has to lose time on this :)

Edit: add compiler output:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:6:30: error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_load(std::shared_ptr<int>*)'
  auto n = std::atomic_load(&p);
                              ^
test.cpp:6:30: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.3/atomic:906:5: note: template<class _ITp> _ITp std::atomic_load(const std::atomic<_ITp>*)
     atomic_load(const atomic<_ITp>* __a) noexcept
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.3/atomic:906:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:6:30: note:   'std::shared_ptr<int>' is not derived from 'const std::atomic<_ITp>'
  auto n = std::atomic_load(&p);
                              ^
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.3/atomic:911:5: note: template<class _ITp> _ITp std::atomic_load(const volatile std::atomic<_ITp>*)
     atomic_load(const volatile atomic<_ITp>* __a) noexcept
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.3/atomic:911:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:6:30: note:   'std::shared_ptr<int>' is not derived from 'const volatile std::atomic<_ITp>'
  auto n = std::atomic_load(&p);
                              ^
```

Comment: You forgot to post the most valuable piece of information: error message

Comment: The page you linked to talks specifically about GCC versions and *language* compatibility. `atomic_load(shared_ptr)` is a question of library compatibility. And the page on that is decidedly less clear.

Comment: It is possible, though perhaps unwise, to backport `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_atomic.h` locally and compile with gcc 4.8 or 4.9. I'm unaware though if there were other semantic changes that might make that subtly incompatible in a way that does not prevent compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an omission in the libstdc++ library. See this [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57250).
The addition of this feature is mentioned in the [GCC 5 Release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) in "Runtime library" section.
It is not shown at your link because it is library, not compiler feature.
There is [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) on library feature support, but unfortunately it does not say in which version a feature has appeared first time.

Comment: You can do a search through the [documentation for each GCC version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), but it's pretty annoying